# Is there a way to add a parameter to all the Jenkin jobs I have access to?

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-builder

I am trying to add a parameter called timeout in all my Jenkin jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are called [Jenkins Pipeline Environment](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/set-jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-list/#:%7E:text=Jenkins%20environment%20variable%20is%20a,variable%20is%20of%20string%20type.) variables.

> The Jenkins pipeline environment variables facilitate the benefits like :

> 1. Injection of sensitive data at runtime to avoid the hardcoding into the pipeline.
> 2. Addition of job parameters available only at runtime, but not at design time.
> 3. Boolean values set in environment variables help certain toggle stages in a pipeline via a parameter that describes a specific subset of tests you want to run.
> 4. Providing IDs of credentials defined in Jenkins.

I think the first point is the benefit you are looking for.